# Проброс текущего пользователя в конструтируемый json.net запрос

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, json.net

У меня есть простой класс запроса:

```
public class Query
{
    public Query(int currentUserId, int personId)
    {
        this.CurrentUserId = currentUserId;
        this.PersonId = personId;
    }

    public int CurrentUserId { get; }

    public int PersonId { get; }
}
```

Который json.net создаёт прямо из входных параметров:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<object> Details(Query query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
}
```

Проблема в том, что я хочу установить query.CurrentUserId равным текущему пользователю:

```
 int.Parse(this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value)
```

В то время как подставляется из входных параметров запроса (что мне совершенно не нужно, т.к. любой сможет присылать любой запрос).

Можно ли каким-то способом указать Json.Net переписывать это поле при создании?

Comment: Вам надо использовать кастомный ModelBinder для этого параметра.

Comment: Допилить до работающего решения см. статью на хабре: https://habr.com/en/post/492820/